# How can i get one button to do multiple tasks depending on how many times it has been clicked? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

How can i get one button to do multiple tasks depending on how many times it has been clicked? (Javascript)

For example button is clicked - alert "button clicked once" button gets clicked again - alert "button clicked twice" button is clicked again - alert" button has been clicked three times!"

Sorry if its a noob question, the reason is I AM A NOOB!!!

Comment: You could use `onclick` and `ondblclick` events.

Answer (score 2):

**Fiddle demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/h9DbF/

in js:

```
var clickTimes = 0;

function doSomethingOnClick() {
    clickTimes++;
    switch(clickTimes) {
        case 1:
            alert('Button clicked once');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Button clicked twice');
            break;
        default:
            alert('Button clicked ' + clickTimes + ' times');
    }
    //Do something else
}
```

in html:

```
<button onclick="doSomethingOnClick()">Press me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a var that will increment when the button is clicked, and you can switch that var so you can do an action depending on the number of clicks for example:

```
var clicks = 0;
function someFunction(){
    clicks++;
    switch (clicks){
        case 1:
            //do something when its clicked only once
            break;
    }
}
```

And thats it.